# ¿Cómo puedo confirmar que compartió mi aplicación en redes sociales?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-intent

estoy intentando hacer que mi aplicación pueda ser compartida por los usuarios en whatsapp, fb y twiter, he visto que es posible con intent de esta manera:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
intent.setType("text/plain");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, getResources().getString(R.string.mensajeShared));
intent.setPackage("com.whatsapp");
startActivity(intent);
```

Hasta ahí todo bien, el problema con el que me enfrento es que intento tener un sistema de recompensas, y el usuario no puede recibir dicha recompensa a menos que se confirme que SI envío o compartió dicho texto y no sólo dio click al botón, no tengo idea de como hacer dicha confirmación, espero alguien pueda ayudarme. Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Y... si pudieras saber lo que paso en otra aplicacion creo que descubririas algo magico.. no creo que puedas saber si le dio send al mensaje de whatapp o solo borro el mensaje.. tal vez solo dar la recompensa cuando el otro entre, como hacen todas las apps conocidas??? por algo usan sistemas de recompensas con codigos...

Comment: He estado investigando y tal vez pueda hacerse algo con la clase Broadcastreceiver, y perdón bro pero si hay aplicaciones que no te recompensas por sólo entrar.

Comment: Buenisimo si se puede!!! Pero tal vez esas app tienen apis para eso?

Comment: A eso intento encontrar respuesta, si es sólo con un api la cual no es pública o se puede hacer sin apis, pero bueno gracias por tu ayuda amigo.

Comment: Creo que no se puede, porque la otra aplicación no te dará feedback de lo que ha hecho el usuario (whatsapp, telegram, gmail, etc) Pero si quieres recompensar, podrías generar un código por usuario que vaya en la url de invitación y, cuando el nuevo user cliquee, se puede guardar en backend que efectivamente tu usuario ha hecho una invitación más

Answer (score 1, accepted):

De forma fácil no creo que se pueda, debería ser algo firmado entre las dos aplicaciones y que se conozcan entre ellas. Estuve trabajando en una app que estaba intentando hacer esto también, saber si un usuario ha compartido una noticia enviada des de nuestra app, pero no lo pudimos solucionar, una solución podría ser que el link que usas para compartir tu app o lo que quieras compartir no sea directamente el de Google Play o algo similar, sino un link creado por ti que se ha generado específicamente para ese usuario y en tu backend tener constancia de ello y cada vez que un usuario clicke en ese link podrías ser notificado, pero tendrías que tener en cuenta también que un usuario no pueda clickar más de una vez para que el "compartidor" sea beneficiado más de una vez.

Si es sólo compartir un link y no necesitas que se descargue nada tiraría por esta opción, si necesitas saber si se ha descargado algo ahí podrías jugar también con el UUID del dispositivo y en tu app tener un check si existe ese UUID y viene de parte de alguien y entonces podrías recompensarlo.

Espero haberte ayudado, si no entendí muy bien la pregunta házmelo saber y edito mi respuesta.

Comment: Muchas gracias, sí entendiste bien la pregunta. Me has dado algunas ideas. Gracias.